# Sidwaystables error: Package rotating loaded after tablefootnote

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable

How can I solve this problem about `sideway`table`s?

```
Package tablefootnote Error: Package rotating loaded after tablefootnote. 
\begin{document}
```

My document class and packages are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%% packages   
\input{packages}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's in the file `packages.tex`? What happens if you place the instruction `\usepackage{rotating}` before `\input{packages}`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mico. When I place \usepackage{rotating} before \input{packages} I do not face error. Thanks for your suggestion!